# Pythonで連番のオブジェクトを宣言する際の良い書き方について

Tags: python, python3

Pythonで

```
global r1 r2 r3
```

や

```
return r1 r2 r3
```

と宣言する際に

```
global 'r'+ str(i) for i in range(1, 4)
```

のようにするとinvalid syntaxになってしまいます。
回避する良い方法はないでしょうか。
（この書き方をするとdefの引数を設定してr3 r4 r5 r6のように可変にできると考えているのですが…）

Comment: 目的に合致するか分かりませんが、同様の議論にいくつかの記事があって、色々考察されているようですが、辞書かリストを使うのが良いらしいです。 [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/9014308), [Changing variable names with Python for loops duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1060090/9014308), [How to rename variables in a loop in Python duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16057689/9014308), [SOLVED how do i rename a variable in python?](https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1604705/solved-how-do-i-rename-a-variable-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

普通、連番のついた変数名を生成するのは避けて、タプルやリストを使います。これらであれば添え字で自然に連番がつきます。

つまり、こうするのではなく、

```
r1 = "aaa"
r2 = "bbb"
r3 = "ccc"
```

こうします。

```
result = ("aaa", "bbb", "ccc")

# または

result = ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]

# 各要素には result[0], result[1], result[2] として参照できます
# タプルは長さが決まっているので、今回の例ではタプルの方が向いていそうです
```

また、辞書の形にしてもう少し柔軟に名前をつけることもできます。